# Explicit iteration in Gridview and using findControl returns Nothing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to loop through GridView control. It contains radio button and I would like to set it's checked property based on certain condition. However, the findControl method returns nothing.

Here is the aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewInfo"
                runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                DataKeyNames="Result_ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="3%" HeaderText="SELECT">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input name="RadioButtonResultID" 
                       id="RadioButtonResultID" type="radio" 
                       value='<%# Eval("Result_ID") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Characteristics" 
                        DataField="Characteristics" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
    Private Sub HighlightSelectedRow(ByVal id As String)
        Dim rowCount As Int32 = 0

        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridViewLabInfo.Rows
            If (GridViewLabInfo.DataKeys(rowCount).Value.ToString() = id) Then
                row.CssClass = "SelectedRowStyle"

                'Both of the below lines are failing
                TryCast(row.FindControl("RadioButtonResultID"), RadioButton).Checked = True
                CType(row.FindControl("RadioButtonResultID"), RadioButton).Checked = True

            End If
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why can't we set checked value here? any reference please.

Comment: place a runat=server in the tags of that control.

Answer (score 1):

You cast is wrong. That is not a asp.net radio button (RadioButton), but is a HTML one,

So your cast in in this case should be:

```
TryCast(row.FindControl("RadioButtonResultID"), HtmlInputRadioButton ).Checked = True
```

And you don't even need the cast, but this should work:

```
Dim MyRadioBut As HtmlInputRadioButton = row.FindControl("RadioButtonResultID")
MyRadioBut.Checked = True
```

However, in BOTH of the above cases? You can't pick up the control in code behind unless you state that control is rendered by the server.

You need to add the runat="server".

eg this:

```
 <input name="RadioButtonResultID" 
                   id="RadioButtonResultID" type="radio" 
                   value='<%# Eval("Result_ID") %>' runat="server" />
```